# A non-UFD such that $a^2 \mid b^2$ does not lead to $a\mid b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, divisibility, examples-counterexamples

> Is there any non-UFD that is a commutative ring such that $a^2 \mid b^2$ does not always lead to $a\mid b$?

It would be preferable if examples are something that does not involve monomials/polynomials, and there are some integer parts in the non-UFD (for example, gaussian integers have integer parts, though gaussian integer is UFD).

Answer (score 7):

Let $\,a = 2,\  b=\sqrt{12}\,$ in $\,\Bbb Z[\sqrt{12}]$

Comment: +1 a non-maximal order is surely the simplest way to go. At least if we insist that the ring should be a domain (without that requirement the question is rather dull).

Answer (score 3):

Let $a=4$, $b=8$ in $4{\bf Z}$.

Comment: That's as may be, but OP specifically asked for a **non**-UFD.